# Django: API call issue while running on gunicorn

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, django-deployment

I use [Rchilli](http://www.rchilli.com/) resume parser for parsing resume. It works fine while running on `python manage.py runserver` . I am getting an xml data as api response. But while running on gunicorn I'm getting an html response saying that *"The service is temporarily unavailable"*. Is there something need to be changed on the configuration of gunicorn to get this fixed? 
 As the project is still under development, I'm using only gunicorn for deploying the application. I am using this Method:[Lessons Learned From The Dash: Easy Django Deployment](http://ericholscher.com/blog/2010/aug/16/lessons-learned-dash-easy-django-deployment/) for deploying the application without nginx.

Comment: Are you running both from the same machine? This sounds like a network problem.

Comment: Yeah.. After running on gunicorn and seeing it isn't working, I tried 'python manage.py runserver' on the same server. And that seems to be working fine.

Comment: Anup, can we get in touch for the issue, you can catch us on support@rchilli.com or Skype: rchilli.support ----- Rchilli Team